# react js Module not found: Can't resolve 'file-saver'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blob, filesaver.js

I'm following a tutrotial and all off a sudden i'm getting this error . I've tried all solution and reinstall module. but in other class the same code work

this is my code

```
import fileSaver from 'file-saver';

uploadPensiun(event) {
        const files = event.target.files
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('Pensiun', files)
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/uploadpensiun', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: 'Pensiun',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        
    }
```

anyone can help me please?

Comment: Have you installed ```file-saver```? if not then install it by ```npm install file-saver```

Comment: Did you try running `npm install file-saver`?

Comment: i've running npm install file-saver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `file-saver`

with npm:

`npm install file-saver`

or with yarn:

`yarn add file-saver`